# Add Increment to create a path on SQL to be used for a CrystalReport

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, filepath

I am trying to come up with a the correct path for my Crystal report to pick the correct .pdf files. Here is what I have on SQL:

```
CASE 
    WHEN pd.pdCode like 'CUST%'
    THEN 'Y:\300 ORDER PROCESSING\Majid Ahmadi\' + CAST(ord.ordPONumber as nvarchar(25)) + '_Custom' + '.pdf'     --Added 2018-05-23 by MA
    ELSE Null
    END AS imageFilePath
```

And results:

Y:\300 ORDER PROCESSING\Majid Ahmadi\53244_Custom.pdf

Problem is I have multiple files that I want to pick. Like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHyOb.png)

(picture in the link)

Any suggestion to modify my path?

Comment: Use `'CUSTOM*.pdf'`?

Comment: This is the result I get: Y:\300 ORDER PROCESSING\Majid Ahmadi\53244_Custom*.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could use change the THEN to

```
THEN 'Y:\300 ORDER PROCESSING\Majid Ahmadi\' + CAST(ord.ordPONumber as nvarchar(25)) + '_' + pd.pdCode + '.pdf'
```